# Is there an expression for when someone fabricates a quote?

Tags: expressions

I recently came across a thread on some forum, where two people were arguing, and then one of the two started using quotes where the content was completely different from what was actually being said.

It went roughly like that (paraphrasing):

> A:
> I just proved that you are wrong.

> B:
>
> > A:
> > I’m stupid and a liar.

At first I thought of “misquoting”, but it sounds more like distorting or modifying. In this case, it’s neither a distortion nor a modification, but a complete fabrication disguised as a quote.

Is there a word or expression to describe that?

Comment: You’ll need to exit to add a better explanation.  I’m not following your current example at all.

Comment: Yes, this is *misquoting* in the extreme to win an argument. A change in tone, a little twist, and a complete lie are just different ways to misquote someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to it as

> ***putting words into someone's mouth***

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20words%20in%2Finto%20someone%27s%20mouth#:%7E:text=Save%20Word-,Definition%20of%20put%20words%20in%2Finto%20someone%27s%20mouth,put%20words%20in%20my%20mouth.) defines this phrase as:

> to suggest that someone said or meant something that he or she did not actually say or mean
>
> Ex. ***Don't put words in my mouth***. I wasn't defending his actions, despite what you may think.

[WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/put_words_in_someone%27s_mouth.html) gives ***twisting someone's words*** as a synonym.

Answer (score -1):

Made from **whole cloth**

> > pure fabrication —usually used in the phrase out of whole cloth

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whole%20cloth

A less polite and more colorful one:

“You pulled that out of your [crude word for derrière].”